# How to create database in android studio. as the code i wrote is not creating database in ddms

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, ddms

I wrote a code for registration but database is not created in android device manager. what should i do. No data file is been created in DDMS--> file explorer-->data.Code is running but cannot see database. i'm running app on phone and not emulator

**code**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Facultyreg extends AppCompatActivity implements    View.OnClickListener {
EditText name, address, qualification, salary, username, password, repassword;
Button submit;
SQLiteDatabase db;
ContentValues cv;
Cursor c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facultyreg);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sname);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    qualification = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qualification);
    salary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.salary);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    repassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.repassword);


    submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);

    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    try {
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("CMS",MODE_PRIVATE,null);


        db.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS FACULTY(FID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "NAME varchar(50) NOT NULL,"
                + "ADDRESS varchar(50),"
                + "QUALIFICATION varchar(50) ,"
                + "SALARY varchar(50) NOT NULL,"
                + "USERNAME varchar(50) ,"
                + "PASSWORD varchar(100))");
    }
      catch (Exception e){
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Facultyreg.this, "DB not         created.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          toast.show();

      }


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.add) {
        onRegister();

    }
}


public void onRegister(){

    String fname= name.getText().toString();
    String add= address.getText().toString();
    String qual= qualification.getText().toString();
    String sal = salary.getText().toString();
    String uname = username.getText().toString();
    String pass= password.getText().toString();
    String repass= (repassword.getText().toString());

    if(fname.isEmpty()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Facultyreg.this, "Please Enter Name.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        name.setFocusable(true);
        name.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(add.isEmpty()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Facultyreg.this, "Please Enter Address.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        address.setFocusable(true);
        address.requestFocus();
    }

    else if(sal.isEmpty()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Facultyreg.this, "Please Enter Salary.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        salary.setFocusable(true);
        salary.requestFocus();
    }

    else if(qual.isEmpty()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Facultyreg.this, "Please Enter qualification.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        qualification.setFocusable(true);
        qualification.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(pass.isEmpty()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Facultyreg.this, "Please Enter Password.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        password.setFocusable(true);
        password.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(repass.isEmpty()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Facultyreg.this, "Please Re-enter Password.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        repassword.setFocusable(true);
        repassword.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(!pass.equals(repass)){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Facultyreg.this, "Passwords do not match. Try again!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        repassword.setFocusable(true);
        repassword.requestFocus();
    }


    else if(uname.isEmpty()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Facultyreg.this, "Please Enter Your Username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        username.setFocusable(true);
        username.requestFocus();
    }
    else
    {
        cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("NAME",fname);
        cv.put("ADDRESS",add);
        cv.put("QUALIFICATION",qual);
        cv.put("SALARY",sal);
        cv.put("USERNAME",uname);
        cv.put("PASSWORD",pass);
        db.insert("FACULTY", null, cv);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Facultyreg.this, "Registered.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        Intent in=new Intent();
        setResult(175,in);
        finish();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Testing on emulator or device?

Comment: see in  DDMS--> file explorer-->data-->data-->com.yourpackagename-->database.

Comment: DDMS--> file explorer-->data , data file is not opening folder are not created inside data

Comment: data->data is not accessible on a non-rooted device

Comment: yah you need rooted device..!

Comment: Use ORM database like DBFlow or SugarORM,where creating and writing data to database is much simpler.  http://codex2android.blogspot.in/2016/03/sugar-orm-with-sqlite-android-part-i.html

Answer (score 1):

DDMS File explorer allows access to `data->data` only on emulators and rooted devices.

You can view and browse an `SQLite` database on PC. Download the db browser from [here](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Now, to get the `SQLite` db file from a **non-rooted** device, open a **command prompt** and run the following commands by adding your proper **package name** and **db file name**

```
adb shell "run-as com.package.name cp /data/data/com.package.name/databases/dbname.sqlite /sdcard/dbname.sqlite"
adb pull /sdcard/dbname.sqlite
```

The `SQLite` db file will be where you opened the command prompt from. Just open it in the db browser you downloaded earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , You can see database in DDMS with the help of emulater (rooted device).

If you want to see database with real device, then you can copy that database and save into one folder.After that you can see database with the help of "DB Browser software" or other.

for copy database into one folder you can use this.

```
 /****************use for create folder in device*****************/
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator + "CMS";

        File folder = new File(path);
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }
        if (success) {
            // Do something on success
        } else {
            // Do something else on failure
        }
       /****************use for create folder in device*****************/

        /****************use for copy data from database*****************/
        if (sd.canWrite()) {

            String currentDBPath = "/data/data/"+ getPackageName()+"/databases/CMS";// db path

            String backupDBPath = "dbname.db";
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(path, backupDBPath);
            //to get the run time db file
            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = null;
                try {
                    src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                FileChannel dst = null;
                try {
                    dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

          }
        /****************use for copy data from database*****************/
```

**You find database in CMS folder in your real device.**

I hope this will help you. thanks

Sorry for my english.